# is the limit of ergodic functions still ergodic?

Tags: ergodic-theory, fa.functional-analysis

under what conditions is the limit of a sequence of ergodic functions still ergodic? are there simple counter-examples to this general statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A rotation $z\mapsto e^{2\pi i\alpha} z$ as a self-map of the unit circle is ergodic wrto the length measure iff $\alpha$ is irrational. So any sequence of irrational numbers converging to a rational number produces a counterexample.